# how to bind image asp.net by jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
  debugger;
  var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(response.d);
  var xml = $(xmlDoc);
  var customers = xml.find("Table");
  var repeatColumns = parseInt("<%=dlCustomers.RepeatColumns == 0 ? 1 : dlCustomers.RepeatColumns %>");
  var rowCount = Math.ceil(customers.length / repeatColumns);
  var i = 0;
  while (i < repeatColumns * rowCount) {
    var row = $("[id*=dlCustomers] tr").eq(0).clone(true);
    for (var j = 0; j < repeatColumns; j++) {
      var customer = $(customers[i]);

      if (customer.length == 0) {

        $("table:last", row).remove();
      } else {
        imagetxturl = $(".image").attr('src', customer.find("imgurl").text());
        $(".pname", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("pname").text());
        $(".mrp", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("mrp").text());
        $(".shortdesc", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("shortdesc").text());
        $(".bv", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("bv").text());
        $(".dp", row).eq(j).html(customer.find("dp").text());

      }
      i++;

    }
    $("[id*=dlCustomers]").append(row);
  }
  $("[id*=dlCustomers] tr").eq(0).remove();
  $("[id*=dlCustomers]").show();
}
```

> Repeat same image but all data is correctly getting. The issue is not get correct image.
>   I am also sharing screenshot. please take look and help me to resolve this.
>   I was give our function code. Please tell where i was wrong.
>    Please help to resolve this issue. `see images`

[image]

Comment: you are assign to entire class the img url, then it will be same image only, //  imagetxturl = $(".image").attr('src', customer.find("imgurl").text()); // check this part

Comment: I know this line have issue but how i will fix this ?

Comment: A side-note: Your client-side code doesn't have anything with ASP.NET to do. Your browser runs html/javascript regardless of server technology.

Comment: How to fix this ? How i will call different url every time. Which is already in database ?

Comment: you are doing `var customers = xml.find("Table");` and then trying to get image url using `customer.find("imgurl").text()` So you need to debug the code and check why `customer.find("imgurl").text()` gives you the same URL...